# Discord.py Using the same dropdown view multiple times but each new time it is awaited, update the values in its ui.select and in the await message

Tags: discord, discord.py

So I'm making a simple rpg game that has a battle mechanic like pokemon where when the player (hero) first meets an enemy, they're given a dropdown of options to do (with the player's health displayed), with one being to attack the enemy. That kicks off a process of giving damage to the enemy and then the enemy attacking the player and giving damage to them. Then the player is then presented with the same dropdown as before and it goes on like that until either the hero dies or the enemy. The problem is that after the first attack works for both health's updating correctly, the second time the player attacks, their health and the enemy's is reset back to it's inital value before the first attack, and then the newest damage is applied to their health. Essentially every attack works as expected but the health variables are being reset to their original state.

hero_currenthealth and monster_currenthealth are global variables. They're first set values in the beginning of the main class. The batlle logic is setup like this (the ... is unrelated code):

```
class get_hero_actions(View): # battle actions input (will be used when hero fights a monster)
                        def __init__(self, rpg_cog, monster_currenthealth, hero_currenthealth,...original_message=None):
                            super().__init__()

                            self.rpg_cog = rpg_cog
                            self.monster_currenthealth = monster_currenthealth
                            self.hero_currenthealth = hero_currenthealth
                            ...
                            self.original_message = original_message
                        
                        @discord.ui.select(
                            placeholder="Choose an action to do",
                            options=[
                                discord.SelectOption(label="Physical Attack", value="1"),...]
                        )
                        async def select_callback(self, interaction, select):

                            select.disabled=True

                            if select.values[0] == "1": # chose to physical attack
                                if self.hero_attack_hits(): 
                                    damage = self.calculate_hero_damage() # calculate damage
                                    self.monster_currenthealth = monster_currenthealth
                                    self.monster_currenthealth -= damage
                                    
                                    if self.monster_currenthealth <= 0: # monster died (ran out of health)
                                       await ctx.author.send(f"You defeated **{monster_name}**")
                                    
                                    else: # monster attack
                                        await self.monster_attack()

                            self.stop()

# # Hero Attack section ############################################################################

                        def calculate_hero_damage(self):
                            ...
                            return hero_base_damage # damage dealt to monster

                       
             
# # Monster Attack section ############################################################################
           
                        # Monster's attack
                        async def monster_attack(self):

                            monster_damage = self.calculate_monster_damage()
                            self.hero_currenthealth = hero_currenthealth # needed this for the first attack to correctly update the health
                            self.hero_currenthealth -= monster_damage
                            if self.hero_currenthealth <= 0: # hero died (ran out of health)

                                await ctx.author.send("You have been defeated!")
                            else: # hero's turn
                                get_hero_actions_view = get_hero_actions(self.rpg_cog, self.monster_currenthealth, self.hero_currenthealth, ... self.original_messag) 
                                updated_message = await ctx.author.send(f"_ _ \nYour current health is **{self.hero_currenthealth}**/**{hero_totalhealth}** \n\n **{monster_name}** current health is **{self.monster_currenthealth}**", view=get_hero_actions_view)
                                #get_hero_actions_view.original_message = hero_actions

                                # Edit the original message with the updated information
                                await self.original_message.edit(content=updated_message.content, view=get_hero_actions_view)

                            ## After sending the original message, initialize the get_hero_actions with the original message
                            #get_hero_actions_view = get_hero_actions(self, monster_currentagility, hero_currentluck, monster_currenthealth, hero_currentmana, hero_currenthealth)
                            #hero_actions = await ctx.author.send(f"_ _ \nYour current health is **{hero_currenthealth}**/**{hero_totalhealth}**", view=get_hero_actions_view)
                            #get_hero_actions_view.original_message = hero_actions

                        # Calculates physical damage based on monster's strength
                        def calculate_monster_damage(self):
                            ...
                            return monster_base_damage # damage dealt to hero

# # Second dropdown (Zone 1 First Battle Actions) section ############################################################################
                              
                    get_hero_actions_view  = get_hero_actions(self, monster_currenthealth, hero_currenthealth, ...)
                    hero_actions = await ctx.author.send(f"_ _ \nYour current health is **{hero_currenthealth}**/**{hero_totalhealth}**", view=get_hero_actions_view) # bot gives player dropdown (asking to choose an action)
                    get_hero_actions_view.original_message = hero_actions
```

I tried some of the commented out code, as well as not using "self." in front of the variables.
I think it has something to do with "get_hero_actions_view.original_message = hero_actions"

Comment: This question is very specific and requires people to understand all of what you're trying to do to help you. Your question will be more likely to get an answer if you provide a generalizable [mre].

Comment: I get what you're saying. I can generalize my question to be: how to make a view with variables in it that get updated and pass those updates to it so that it always displays the most up-to-date values when awaited